# Setting the datacontext of all sub-views in parent view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML file of the form

**CTC.XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="KPI.CTC.UI.CTC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:KPI.CTC.UI"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Industry">
            <uc:Industry DataContext="{}"/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Templates">
            <uc:Templates DataContext="{}"/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Item Calcs">
            <uc:ItemCalcs DataContext="{}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

where `Industry.xaml`,`Templates.xaml` and `ItemCalcs.xaml` have respective ViewModels in a separate namespace `KPI.CTC.ViewModel`. I wished to know is it possible to set the `DataContext` of all the 3 views in `CTC.xaml` only. I do not want to perform the tedious task of setting the `DataContext` separately for individual views.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are they existing objects or do you want to create new ones? if you want to create new ones, how about `<uc:Industry ..><DataContext><ctc:IndustryViewModel /></DataContext></uc:Industry>`?

Comment: they are existing classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `FrameworkElement.DataContext` Property page on MSDN, you should see a section named *Dependency Property Information*:

[image]

This tells us that the `DataContext DependencyProperty` has a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` value of `Inherits`, which means that the `DataContext` property will *automatically be inherited by child controls*. Therefore, *if* you had wanted to set the `DataContext` of all of the child controls to the same value as the parent, then this would happen automatically, but this is the only situation where this would happen.

So unless your situation is as above, you're going to have to write some code somewhere... the only question is where. Perhaps the simplest method is for you to use `DataTemplate`s, although this will only work if you are data binding an instance of a different type of object for each user control. Try adding these `DataTemplate`s into your `Application.Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IndustryViewModel}">
    <Views:Industry />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ItemCalcsViewModel}">
    <Views:ItemCalcs />
</DataTemplate>
```

Using this method will free you from ever having to manually set a `DataContext` property. Just add a new `DataTemplate` for each view/view model pair that you have and then you can display your views/`UserControl`s like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelIntanceProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do it and it depends on your application architecture, complexity, etc. Some involve using so-called [IoC containers](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wpf%20mvvm%20ioc%20container).

The three simplest would be:

1. Declare VMs directly in XAML:

   ```
   <TabItem Header="Industry">
       <uc:Industry>
           <uc:Industry.DataContext>
               <vm:IndustryViewModel />
           </uc:Industry.DataContext>
       </uc:Industry>
   </TabItem>
   ```

   etc.
2. Declare VMs as 'main' ViewModel properties:

   ```
   public IndustryViewModel IndustryViewModel
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   ```

   etc.
3. If `TabControl` ViewModels inherit from one base class, you may delcare a `Dictionary`
   in 'main' VM containing the 3 `TabControl` ViewModels:

   ```
   Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase> ViewModels
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   ViewModels = new Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase>();
   ViewModels.Add("Industry", new IndustryViewModel());
   // and so on...
   ```

   and assign it in XAML:

   ```
   <TabItem Header="Industry">
       <uc:Industry DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[Industry]}"/>
   </TabItem>
   ```

Comment: -1 for suggesting such a terrible idea. Judging by your `ViewModels` collection property, you are suggesting that the question author hold a collection of instances of *all* of their view models... that means unnecessarily wasting resources by holding *all* of them in memory - you've clearly never written a large WPF application before. A far better solution would be to have just one property of type `BaseViewModel` and set an instance of the current relevant view model to it whenever the view changes. It also doesn't really answer the user's question.

Comment: You've misunderstood me. I've nowhere written about having *all* of VMs in single dictionary. VM of the Window declares and fills 3-item dictionary of VMs for TabControl. Also, I've actually finished writing a large WPF application, so your crystall ball is clearly broken.

Comment: *I've nowhere written about having all of VMs in single dictionary.* True, but you also didn't write what *was* supposed to go in there. However, now that you have, I'll remove the down vote... ah... I can't remove it now until you edit your question.

Comment: Does this fulfill your needs? ;)